# Predefined arrays in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I've come across a pretty strange problem where the amount of memory used by the program doesn't seem to change, regardless of the size of the array.

I'm using the Arduino compiler and an example of the code is below:

```
unsigned char ary[]={0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,
    0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,};
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

If I remove the array and recompile, the file size is still the same. Maybe I've been out of the coding scene for a while, any thoughts on what might be going on?

```
unsigned char ary[] = {
  0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,
    0x01,0x02,0x03,0x04,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03,
};

unsigned char var1;

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      int res = myFunction(&ary[0]);

    }

    void loop() {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

    }

    int myFunction (unsigned char *adr){
      //unsigned char b=4;
      unsigned char c;
      for(int n=0;n<1;n++)c=adr[0];
      var1=c;
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Note that the executable _file_ is not the same as the _loaded program_. There may be headers of minimum sizes, fix-up information, etcetera, which, when loaded are all gone.

Comment: The file size has very little relationship to the memory used.  I can fill up your virtual memory with just a few lines of code.

Comment: It might be optimized out if it's not used anywhere

Comment: The original file I was working on had an array of 5Kb but the output compiled file size was always the same around 600 bytes giver or take. I did try using it in a line of code in the case of it being optimised out of the program for non use. still got the same resulting file size in the program.

Comment: So, check this out, I've added a new test code block below my original query, interesting things happen when we ghost out the code 'for(int n=0;n<1;n++)'  leaving the 'c=adr[0];' although the for loop is not really changing the array location (always set to zero) the program will store the entire array in the compiled code only if for loop is used.

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino compiler takes out automatically parts of the code that are not used anywhere: Dead Code Elimination.

If you for example add

```
ary[0]  = 5;
```

in the setup or loop part, the sketch size grows and will continue to grow when adding elements to `ary`.

Without the added line I have a sketch of 444 bytes (and 9 bytes of dynamic memory). With the line added it's 494 bytes (and 31 bytes of memory).

Comment: To add, I tried adding const keyword but no change to the output. Using your example regarding attempting to modify the array location 0 in my main code did something, the compiler now 'probably correctly' complains that my 5k file is too large, where previously it seemed happy with it. Its odd that it only flags this up when i attempt to add one byte to existing array location.

Comment: I tried compiling with other software, seems to include the whole array in the final output. Perhaps something quirky with arduino compiler?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help folks, Optimisation settings which vary on each platform I'm using are producing different results. Tried disabling optimisation for arduino and it built the full file size (regardless of the data being accessed or not). Here is a link on how to do this if anyone is interested (remember to save a copy before changing):

[Arduino optimising](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-IDE-16x-compiler-optimisations-faster-code/)

Regards